# How to get list of certain strings in a list of files using bash?

Tags: bash

The title is maybe not really descriptive, but I couldn't find a more concise way to describe the problem.

I have a directory containing different files which have a name that e.g. looks like this:

```
{some text}2019Q2{some text}.pdf
```

So the filenames have somewhere in the name a year followed by a capital Q and then another number. The other text can be anything, but it won't contain anything matching the format year-Q-number. There will also be no numbers directly before or after this format.

I can work something out to get this from one filename, but I actually need a 'list' so I can do a for-loop over this in bash.

So, if my directory contains the files:

```
costumerA_2019Q2_something.pdf
costumerB_2019Q2_something.pdf
costumerA_2019Q3_something.pdf
costumerB_2019Q3_something.pdf
costumerC_2019Q3_something.pdf
costumerA_2020Q1_something.pdf
costumerD2020Q2something.pdf
```

I want a for loop that goes over 2019Q2, 2019Q3, 2020Q1, and 2020Q2.

EDIT:

This is what I have so far. It is able to extract the substrings, but it still has doubles. Since I'm already in the loop and I don't see how I can remove the doubles.

```
find original/*.pdf -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' line; do
   echo $line | grep -oP '[0-9]{4}Q[0-9]'
done
```

Comment: Big problems are sums of small problems. So 1. Create the list of files with `find`. 2. Extract the requested string with `sed` 3. Iterate over the list of files. Remember about `-maxdepth` to `find`. [Sed introduction](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-1). [bashfaq how to read a string line by line](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: I'll edit my question to show what I have so far.

Comment: `how I can remove the doubles` - what are those "doubles"?

Comment: E.g. 2019Q3 is printed three times, but I want it to be printed only once.

Comment: Sure, just `sort -u` the list.

Comment: OK, I will try, but that won't work with my solution since I only get the patterns inside the loop, so there is no list anymore at that time. But maybe I can get it to work with your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# list all _filanames_ that end with .pdf from the folder original
find original -maxdepth 1 -name '*.pdf' -type f -print "%p\n" |
# extract the pattern
sed 's/.*\([0-9]{4}Q[0-9]\).*/\1/' |
# iterate
while IFS= read -r file; do
    echo "$file"
done
```

I used `-print %p` to print just the filename, instead of full path. The GNU sed has `-z` option that you can use with `-print0` (or `-print "%p\0"`).

With how you have wanted to do this, if your files have no newline in the name, there is no need to loop over list in bash (as a rule of a thumb, try to avoid `while read line`, it's very slow):

```
find original -maxdepth 1 -name '*.pdf' -type f | grep -oP '[0-9]{4}Q[0-9]'
```

or with a zero seprated stream:

```
find original -maxdepth 1 -name '*.pdf' -type f -print0 |
grep -zoP '[0-9]{4}Q[0-9]' | tr '\0' '\n'
```

If you want to remove duplicate elements from the list, pipe it to `sort -u`.

Comment: Actually, the underscores were only there to make the pattern clearer. They pattern is not necessary surrounded by underscores. The only common thing is as described in the text: 4 digits, a Q, and an additional digit.

Comment: Thanks. Without using the while loop this indeed does what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, in bash:

```sh
~ > $ ls
costumerA_2019Q2_something.pdf  costumerB_2019Q2_something.pdf
costumerA_2019Q3_something.pdf  other.pdf
costumerA_2020Q1_something.pdf  someother.file.txt

~ > $ for x in `(ls)`; do [[ ${x} =~ [0-9]Q[1-4] ]] && echo $x; done;
costumerA_2019Q2_something.pdf
costumerA_2019Q3_something.pdf
costumerA_2020Q1_something.pdf
costumerB_2019Q2_something.pdf

~ > $ (for x in *; do [[ ${x} =~ ([0-9]{4}Q[1-4]).+pdf ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}; done;) | sort -u
2019Q2
2019Q3
2020Q1
```

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls). Use `for x in *`.